# Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: firefox

the Firefox web browser on Ubuntu 14.04 keeps unexpectedly shutting down as I am downloading.  how do I fix this?

Comment: launch Firefox from terminal by typing `firefox` command and use normally. When Firefox shuts down, you will get error message in terminal . post it here

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling it and see if it solves the problem 
run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox`